# How to assign to values to column in pandas dataframe based on columns in other dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiple-columns

I am trying to analyze some data related to air-routes using pandas. So I have two dataframes:

```
print(airports.head())

           IATA/FAA           Country
Airport ID                           
1               GKA  Papua New Guinea
2               MAG  Papua New Guinea
3               HGU  Papua New Guinea
4               LAE  Papua New Guinea
5               POM  Papua New Guinea

print(routes.head())

        Source airport Destination airport
Airline                                   
2B                 AER                 KZN
2B                 ASF                 KZN
2B                 ASF                 MRV
2B                 CEK                 KZN
2B                 CEK                 OVB
```

Now I want to add two more columns to the dataframe `routes`: "SA country" which represents the country of the source airport and "DA country" which represents the country of the destination airport. For a given `IATA/FAA`, the country can somehow be extracted from the dataframe `airports`. However, I am not able to understand that "somehow". Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary creates from `airports` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html), if some values are not matched get `NaN`:

```
d = airports.set_index('IATA/FAA')['Country'].to_dict()
#works by map by Series but a bit slowier
#d = airports.set_index('IATA/FAA')['Country']
routes['SA country'] = routes['Source airport'].map(d)
routes['DA country'] = routes['Destination airport'].map(d)
```